# A sequence defined as $a(n)=n-a(a(n-1))$ $n\geq 1,\ a(0)=0$, how to prove that $a(n)=⌊(n+1)(-1+√5)/2⌋$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

$a(n)=n-a(a(n-1)), \ n \geq 1,\ a(0)=0$, to prove that
$$
a(n)=⌊(n+1)\cdot \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}⌋.
$$
This is an exercise of "Discrete Mathematics and Its Application".(Supplementary exercise 72 of chapter 5)
this unusual sequence is first defined in Douglas Hofstader's "Gödel, Escher, Bach".
And here is some Hint from the exercise:
Let $$u=(-1+\sqrt{5})/2$$ First show for all n>0 that $$(u*n-⌊u*n⌋)+(u^2*n-⌊u^2*n⌋)=1$$ Then show for all real numbers a with 0≤a<1 and a≠1-u that $$⌊(1+u)*(1-a)⌋+⌊a+u⌋=1
$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is related to the so-called Wythoff sequence (the 'simplest' example of a Beatty Sequence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence ) and you may be able to find some good hints with those terms.

Comment: I tried to apply mathematical induction. And I noticed that $$u^2+u-1=0$$, also tried to apply the hit. I've read the wiki page, but didn't get any idea. Maybe I will continue trying.